# Google charts into JQuery Tab draw issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, socket.io, google-visualization

I am currently trying to move Google charts in which the data is being pulled from the server-side via socket.io and drawing them into JQuery UI Tabs.

The issue am having is that the first report that gets drawn in works fine and looks fine.

The 2nd looks quite wrong, I think its something to do with how am drawing the tables maybe but am unable to find a solution, this issue does not happen when am simply drawing it into divs outside the JQuery UI tabs.

This is the current code I have right now:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var socket = io.connect();
    var result = [];
    google.charts.load('current', {
            packages : ['bar']
        });

 $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });

    socket.on("SQLdipo", function (valueArr) {
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMaterial);
        var data = valueArr;
        function drawMaterial() {

            var result = [['Call Disposition', 'Answered', 'No Answer', 'Busy','Failed']].concat(valueArr);
            var options = {
                height: 350,
                 chart: {
            title: 'Agent Call Dispositions',
            subtitle: 'Agent call states',
          }
            };
            var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);
            var chart1 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chartDipo'));
            chart1.draw(chartdata, options);
        }
    });

    socket.on("SQLmins", function (valueArr) {
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        var data = valueArr;
        function drawChart() {

            var result = [['Total Mins', 'Active','Inactive']].concat(valueArr);
            var options = {
                height: 350,
                 chart: {
            title: 'Agent Activity in seconds',
            subtitle: 'Agent Duration Activity',
          }
            };
            var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);
            var chart2 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chartMins'));
            chart2.draw(chartdata, options);
        }
    });
});
```

I have made a configured a JS fiddle to emulate the issue am having [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/z8u0xL1k/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is the chart is hidden when it is initially drawn.
you could set specific size options *or*...

wait until the tab is activated, before drawing the chart for the first time, as in this example...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui){
      switch (ui.newTab.index()) {
        case 0:
          drawMaterial();
          break;

        case 1:
          drawChart();
          break;
      }
    }
  });

  google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: drawMaterial,
    packages: ['bar']
  });

  function drawMaterial() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Call Disposition', 'Answered', 'No Answer', 'Busy', 'Failed'],
      ['1000', 4, 0, 2, 0],
      ['1001', 4, 2, 0, 0],
      ['1002', 6, 0, 0, 0]
    ]);

    var options = {
      height: 350,
      chart: {
        title: 'Agent Call Dispositions',
        subtitle: 'Agent call states',
      }
    };
    var chart1 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chartDipo'));
    chart1.draw(data, options);
  }

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Call Disposition', 'Answered', 'No Answer', 'Busy', 'Failed'],
      ['1000', 4, 0, 2, 0],
      ['1001', 4, 2, 0, 0],
      ['1002', 6, 0, 0, 0]
    ]);

    var options = {
      height: 350,
      chart: {
        title: 'Agent Call Dispositions',
        subtitle: 'Agent call states',
      }
    };
    var chart1 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chartMins'));
    chart1.draw(data, options);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="tab-div" id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Call Disposition</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Agent Activity</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <div class="report-style" id="chartDipo"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <div class="report-style" id="chartMins"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue am having is when I add socket.io on top of that as in the code above to then use the solution you have suggested, I cant then access those functions.

Comment: Socket.on? When anything is passed to it from serverside it then runs the code and everything wrapped within it. Is that what you mean? Yeah I have tried but Ill double check

Comment: sorry, when you said _I cant then access those functions_ -- did you mean `drawMaterial` and `drawChart` ? not familiar with socket.io...

Comment: Tried increasing the width but it did nothing, Yes I cant access those functions `drawMaterial` and `drawChart` because of socket.io above it

Comment: I do have a work around here based of the example you have given me, but that means making the information I pull from server side and stick it into a global var, which am aware isn't recommended if you would like me to post the suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified it with my own code based of the suggestion you gave @Whitehat which works fine but it means I have to use globals which I believe is not recommended.

What are your thoughts on this or any suggested changes or improvements?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //Global Varibles
    var socket = io.connect();
    var result = [];
    google.charts.load('current', {
            packages : ['bar']
        });

$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui){
      switch (ui.newTab.index()) {
        case 0:
          drawMaterial();
          break;

        case 1:
          drawChart();
          break;
      }
    }
  });

    socket.on("SQLdipo", function (valueArr) {
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMaterial);
        data1 = valueArr;
    });

    socket.on("SQLmins", function (valueArr) {
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        data2 = valueArr;
    });


        function drawMaterial() {

            var result = [['Call Disposition', 'Answered', 'No Answer', 'Busy','Failed']].concat(data1);
            var options = {
                height: 350,
                 chart: {
            title: 'Agent Call Dispositions',
            subtitle: 'Agent call states',
          }
            };
            var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);
            var chart1 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chartDipo'));
            chart1.draw(chartdata, options);
        }

        function drawChart() {

            var result = [['Total Mins', 'Active','Inactive']].concat(data2);
            var options = {
                height: 350,
                 chart: {
            title: 'Agent Activity in seconds',
            subtitle: 'Agent Duration Activity',
          }
            };
            var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);
            var chart2 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chartMins'));
            chart2.draw(chartdata, options);
        }

});
```

Comment: i see now, thanks. that's tough -- and you have to wait on `setOnLoadCallback` because the page reloads?

Comment: I think so, its not an ideal solution but for now it works so I will mark your response as the answer