# visual performance of md-tabs with google charts directive / loading data

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-visualization, angular-material

I've got an Apache Cordova app which uses Angular Material and Google Charts. For the latter I'm using the directives as found here: https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart.

The app is to display analytic data. The graphs are separated in a graph per hour, day, week and month. For this separation, I'm using the md-tabs directive, having a tab for each one.

Now technically speaking everything works. I've got 4 tabs and inside of these tabs I've got two graphs per tab. I've got some code set-up which queries a back-end API, fetches data and binds that to my graph objects. They render the data and all is fine.

Until.... the user switches from one tab to another. Although that works, the transitions are far from smooth. I guess that's because it's doing all sort of stuff behind the scenes which hinders the rendering. By the way, this is a smartphone app we're talking about. Now I know that you cannot expect native rendering performance from a Cordova app, but I'm quite sure it should be able to do better than this.

So I'm now looking for ways to improve this. For instance is there a good way to maybe postpone the data load until the visuals are done transitioning? I prefer smooth UI to loading data as long as the difference isn't seconds. I'd also like a loading indication to overlay the tab contents whilst data is being loaded. As soon as the user switches tabs, I'd expect the transition to go smoothly into the loading indicator of the new tab which would show until the data is there and rendered.

I have tried messing around with ng-if and ng-show and this kind-of helps, but it all feels a bit wonky somehow. So I'm looking for some guidance on these types of scenario's, there must be some best-practices or something? This is also why at this time I'm not sharing any code cause I want the best solution and not one that's based on the stuff I already have (which is most likely sub-optimal, I'm relatively new to Angular).

Comment: one problem may be that the charts are being drawn before they are displayed -- if the size of the chart and/or chart area is not explicitly set, the chart will not display properly when drawn

Comment: @WhiteHat agree, cause when the charts are displayed I see them jump around in size. So the easy fix for that would be to include width and height in the options object, right? And fixed is better then percentage?

Comment: right, fixed will work best, or if you would rather not set a specific size, wait until the tab is selected before drawing the chart --> [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35868433/5090771)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am recently working on md-tabs and encountered with similar issues. I tried using **md-enable-disconnect="true"** which is a experimental attribute in md-tabs api which improved a little performance for me.You can refer a small explanation about this from below url. Hope this helps

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs

Comment: Thanks, definitely will try that one out.

Comment: This helps A LOT indeed, marking it as the answer as it almost completely solves my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Chart rendering performance on any platform can easily be hindered by large numbers of data points.  If you have more data in your data set that the user can actually see and use on a small low performance device, consider summarizing your data before the app consumes it.  This may improve rendering performance.  Of course, how you summarize will depend entirely on what the data is and how it is being used.

Comment: Yes, I already considered and am doing that. The question that remains: what is "a lot"? For my hourly graph, I send 60 data points (one for each minute). For my daily graph it's 24 (per hour), weekly = 7 (will change that) and monthly is max 31. Should not be the problem I think?

Comment: That sounds pretty minimal.  I've talked to people who were pushing hundreds of thousands of data points at the library.  At that level you can't even see all the data points, and it runs really slow.

Comment: Yeah and indeed on a very small form factor I wouldn't see the benefit for doing so.