# Resize multiple Google Charts on different Materialize tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-visualization, materialize

I'm trying to resize Google charts on differents tabs (tabs provided by Materialize) but I can't make it works. Only in the active tab (predetermined) the chart shows as I want, but when I switch to others tabs, the charts don't shows as the active tab (but when I resize the window the active tab and chart resizes as well, but the other charts not ).

I found a JQuery plugin method (by Materialize) to trigger a tab change, but I don't know how (or where) to use it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', 'tab_id');
});
```

An example of my code is [here](https://codepen.io/jimyandres/pen/wdxrzQ)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google charts into JQuery Tab draw issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867562/google-charts-into-jquery-tab-draw-issue)