# Google Chart displayed wrong in tab until I resize the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, google-visualization, semantic-ui

When I click the tab with the Google Chart, first it is showed small and the width style not applied:

[image: Google Chart is not showing properly]

But when I resize the window, it "jumps" as it should look:

[image: Correct way to be]

I would like to see it from the start as it is scaled in the second picture.
Here's one thing I noticed: after it "jumped" to correct format, if I go to a previous tab and resize the window even just a little, when I press the "Macros" tab, it's small again.

This is the code:

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize/master/jquery.throttledresize.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?fake=.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).on("throttledresize", function (event) {
        var options = {
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
        };

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);
        drawChart(data, options);
    });
</script>
```

The CSS from header:

```
<style>
    #chart_wrap {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        height: 0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    #piechart {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

And the HTML code - I am using Semantic UI:

```
<div class="ui tab segment" data-tab="macros">

        <div id="chart_wrap">
            <div id="piechart"></div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: is the tab hidden when the chart is drawn the first time? check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35868433/5090771)...

Comment: For everyone who had the same problem, check @WhiteHat answer. I was using AngularJS and had put it under ng-show=".." which resulted that the chart window size was incorrect.